# GWT 2.7.0 Super Dev Mode, don't recompile server side code after change

Tags: java, gwt, hotswap, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am starting to learn GWT.

I've picked up newest version (2.7.0).

I have wrote `Entry point` class to display start page and to call rpc to server to execute some function.

Every change I made in client side source code in `Entry point` class, cause auto recompile (hot swap), so I can see immediatly changes, that I've apply.

My problem is that it works only for **client side code**.

It dosen't work for **server side code**. To see changes in server side code, I have to stop server and console, and run it again, which is very very annoiyng.

So my question is:

- Is it normal behaviour of gwt app server in SuperDevMode in 2.7.0 version? Or am I doing something wrong?
- How should I deal with that?

Please give me your thougths about it.

By the way: I use GWT with eclipse and Google plugin.

---

EDIT

I wonder what about Maven GWT projects? How to deal with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is normal behavior.

There are several ways to reload the server side code when refreshing without restarting your server:

1. The built in web server does support hot swapping code, but only if you do not modify method or class signatures. If you do change them (or add a class or method), a server restart is required.
2. You might need to configure your Eclipse to auto re-publish any code changes to your web server.
3. There are 3rd Party Eclipse plugins which improve the hot code reloading mechanism, for example [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/), which allows hot code replacement even if you change method or class signatures.

Comment: Can You give me more information about 2 solution? How to build project? How to start server? What server to use, built in Jetty or maybe Tomcat? How to configure that in eclipse? Maybe some usefull link?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat and the "Servers" view (see http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Frwrcview.html) in Eclipse to start and stop it. There's also a "Publish" button in the "Servers" view which I use to publish the changes without a server restart.

Comment: You use `Servers` views/tab to start at first time the server instead of using `RMB -> Run as Web application(GWT Super Dev Mode)` as I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, but to start Tomcat, and not the GWT built-in Jetty server.

Answer (score 1):

There's a "reload webapp" button in DevMode. It's in the "Jetty" tab when using "bare" DevMode, and a yellow double spinning arrow in the Eclipse view when using the GPE. It'll restart the web app just as if you redeployed it in a standalone server.

Comment: I know this solution. It isn't bad. But it doesn't work automatically. I am looking for solution that will do the job for me. Also it won't work for maven gwt projects.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work for maven projects"? If you use an IDE, it'll recompile the classes on-the-fly (well, depending on the IDE) so it'll work the same. Without an IDE then yes you have to trigger a recompile, you can use file watchers for that. Alternative is to not host your server-side code in DevMode but use a servlet container that your IDE can auto-redeploy to.

Comment: I can't  set gwt maven project to work with eclipse. I don't have `run as super dev mode` option like it was with GPE.
**But still it won't work automatically after server code change. I'have to do it manually.**

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:
https://github.com/jbarop/gwt-hotdeployment
 It seems to do the job for developer.

But it is quite old.